# Adjust alertdialog heigh to display all items in listview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I m trying to implement an alert dialog with single choice items, and everything seems fine.

The only problem is that when the list contains multiple items, they are shown correctly, but when the list contains only 2 items, the list is cropped like that.

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2undE.jpg)

How can i adjust my alert dialog to show all items when there are no many items?

This is my code

```
val adapter : ArrayAdapter<*> = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.simple_list_item, items)

MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.dialog_custom_style)
    .setTitle("Dialog title")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, 0) { dialog, position ->
                
        //...
    }           
    .show()
```

This is my simple_list_item layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
    android:padding="16dp"/>
```

And this is my dialog style

```
<style name="Dialog.Custom.Style" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App.Title.Text</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App.Body.Text</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App.Body.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <!--        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton</item>-->
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Start with showing your code. After that tell on which devices Android versions you tried that.

Comment: @blackapps please check my edited question

Comment: please show your `dialog_custom_style`

Comment: @BhavikKalsariya hi, i edited my question to include the dialog style

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom view with a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` then use `wrap_content` on the root.